# Specify Proxy for WebBrowser control in WP7, WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, proxy, windows-phone-8

Is there a possibility of specifying a proxy for a WebBrowser control in a custom application for Windows Phone 7 and/or 8? I have found solutions for hooking into the WebClient like [here](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2012/01/23/Overwriting-the-default-WebRequest-used-by-WebClient.aspx), but the browser control obviously does not consider those settings. Are there any other solutions? Are there any news with regards to that issue in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebBrowser` control is tied to the OS, therefore inheriting the proxy settings that are definied by the user of the device. You can't directly modify them, unless you want to intercept navigation events and feed them directly to your server.

Comment: +1 on programmable proxies not being a supported feature in WP7/WP8.